# Django: Accessing queryset in ModelMultipleChoiceField from template

Tags: django

I'm creating a panel where a user can assign an assignment to other users. I'm attempting to build this with the ModelMultipleChoiceField and a form called AssignedUsersForm

**forms.py**

```
class AssignedUsersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ['users']

    custom_users = CustomUser.objects.all()
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=custom_users, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

**template**

```
  <form method="post" id="assigned_users_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ assigned_users_form.errors }}
      {{ assigned_users_form.non_field_errors }}
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
          {{ assigned_users_form.content.errors }}
          {% for user in assigned_users_form.users %}
          <div class="myradio">
              {{ user }}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Save" name='submit_assigned_users_form'>
      </div>
  </form>
```

I've successfully rendered each of the options for CheckboxSelectMultiple individually in my HTML.

Unfortunately, each iteration of 'user' renders CustomUser object (#) - the default name for the object.

From what I understand, the Checkbox widget does not pass the original queryset to the template. Thus, I'm unable to access the model attributes of each user and render information such as name, profile picture, etc.

Is there a method of accessing the actual object that's represented in the checklist, instead of the _ *str* _ value?

I've considered running a parallel iteration of queryset in the template, but I'm not sure if that's possible in Django.

I've also considered creating custom template tags to access each object based on the id in **str**, but that seems like overkill?

Is there a more intuitive method that I'm missing here?

Comment: Choices should be a tuple of the format ***(redable_value, exact_value)***, so the question is, what do you want to set as the ***readable_value***?

Comment: I suppose the readable_value would be the object, but I don't know how to code that?

Comment: It shouldn't be an object, but the `PK` value of the object

Comment: Yes, I know the pk is stored in the tuple. Do you know the syntax for accessing that id from the template? I'm getting an error that says can't iterate over a bound object

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by creating a template_filter that takes the checkbox value and returns the corresponding object to the template.

**template_tags.py**

```
@register.filter(name='get_user')
def get_user(user_id):
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id.value)
    return user
```

**template**

```
 <form method="post" id="assigned_users_form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ assigned_users_form.errors }}
      {{ assigned_users_form.non_field_errors }}
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
          {{ assigned_users_form.content.errors }}
          {% for user in assigned_users_form.users %}
          <div class="myradio">
              {% with customuser=user.data.value|get_user %}
              {{user.tag}} {{customuser.first_name }}
              {% endwith %}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="Save" name='submit_assigned_users_form'>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Essentially, this code looks at the checkbox widget iteration (user) and gets the value, passes that value to the template tag and then returns the associated object back to the page.

Not the best solution given that you're repeating the query search for each object, rather than gathering them all in one go. But this is the best I could come up with.